# array_walk_recursive return value

Tags: php, arrays

I am using `array_walk_recursive` with a callback function to search within a nested array for specified key:

```
array_walk_recursive($array, array($this, 'walk_array'), $key);
```

Here is the callback function:

```
function walk_array($value, $key, $userdata = '')
{
    if ($key === $userdata)
    {
        self::$items_array[$key] = $value;
        echo $value . "<br />\n";
    }
}
```

The problem is that I can not find a way to **store/return** the found elements from the callback function even though I am using static variable `$items_array` but it always contains the last item processed by the `array_walk_recursive`. On the other hand, if I `echo` the found elements from callback function:

```
echo $value . "<br />\n";
```

All found elements are echoed fine.

How do I return or store the found elements from the callback function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `$key` is going to correspond to multiple values in the nested arrays that you walk through, your `$item_arrays` should have its own array for that key. Otherwise, all you're really doing is overwriting `self::$items_array[$key]` with every value that comes by.

Try this:

```
self::$items_array[$key][] = $value;
```